# Do i have to detach wicket models, if they are used in local variables?

Tags: java, wicket

I am using PropertyModel and Compoundpropertymodel in my wicket application. I use them  as local variables and not as members of the page classes. Do i have to override the onDetach() Function to detach the models when they are local? Or are only member variables serialized into the session?

***Example:***

```
TextField<String> title = new TextField<String>("title", new PropertyModel<String>(position, "title"));
title.setRequired(true);
form.add(positionTitle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, and in most uses of such models in Wicket, the initial assignment is to a local variable, but the object is put into something that is *not* local.

Your `form` is almost certainly a field or contained in something that is, and is serialized into the session.  It contains the `title` field, which in turn contains the model.

So it will be serialized, and yes you should probably implement `onDetach()`.

**Edit:**

As noted in a comment, what really matters is whether it is part of the component hierarchy of a page, rather than whether it is a field.  It does on some level amount to the same thing, as the child components of a page or any other component are held in a field `children` in the superclass `org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer`.

Comment: @Martin Additionally, even if your form isn't a field, it's added to a page (maybe with one or more other components between them). And this page will be serialized for sure.

Comment: @Nicktar - Good point.  I've updated the answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me why you want to detach the model of your TextField, as a TextField needs a model object to write submitted form values to.  If you detach `position` from the PropertyModel, then the TextField won't have a place to write its "title" value to after the user submits the form.  You might want to provide more details about what `position` is, where it was loaded from, and why it needs to be detached between request cycles.  Common practice is to have a safely serializable model object for form components to write their values to.

If you do need to detach the model object of a PropertyModel at the end of each request, chain the PropertyModel to a LoadableDetachableModel.  LDM will load a fresh model object for each request cycle based on your provided `load()` method, and will then automatically null out its reference to that model object on detach to prevent serializing the model object.  If you use a `LoadableDetachableModel<Position>` as the model object of your PropertyModel, then the PropertyModel will detach the LoadableDetachableModel automatically and that will be enough to avoid serializing the `position` object.

Note that you do not need to explicitly call `detach()` on models like the one in your example; Wicket detaches the default models of all Components in the Page hierarchy automatically.  By "default model", I mean a model that gets passed up the `super(...)` chain and eventually becomes the `model` argument of one of the `Component(...)` constructors.

At the end of request processing, the Page calls `detach()` on its children (and those children call `detach()` on their children and so on).  This method (defined in Component) calls `detachModels()`, which in turn detaches the default model of the Component.

Standard Wicket components that commonly use more than one model will detach additional models during `detachModels`.  For example, if you pass DropDownChoice both a model to get/set the selected value, and a model of the list of choices, you will notice that DropDownChoice automatically detaches both of these models at the end of each request.  This is because `AbstractChoice#detachModel()` looks for and detaches a `choices` model, if one has been set.

Chaining models also detach their chained models, so for example if you had

```
Form<User> userForm = new Form<User>("userForm", new CompoundPropertyModel<User>(new DetachableUserModel(...));
```

then the CompoundPropertyModel would be detached automatically by `detachModels`, and that would in turn detach the DetachableUserModel.

Where you DO need to worry about manually detaching models is any case where you use additional models in your code that are neither the default `model` of some component, nor chained into another model that is.  This might be a concern if you are creating a new type of Component that has more than one model object.

Comment: sure, they get detached by wicket but only if they're datachable and implement ´´detach´´ in a meaningful way. PropertyModel only calls detach on the target object (if it's detachable). So, yes it detaches automatically but only if you provide the necessary code and that's what the question was about.

Comment: @Nicktar Got it.  Thanks for the comment.  The original question seems to have confused "model" with "model object".  It mentioned "using PropertyModel and Compoundpropertymodel ... as local variables and not as members of the page classes. Do i have ... to detach the models when they are local?"  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would do :

```
    IModel model = new CompoundPropertyModel(new LoadableDetachableModel(position){
        @Override protected Object load() { return null; }
    });
    Form form = new Form("form", model);
    form.add(
            new TextField("title")
                .setRequired(true));
    add(form);
```

The `detach()` are called in chain at the end of the request. Using a LoadableDetachableModel ensure that the position object is not referenced.

A trick: keep you domain object or value object non serializable. In development configuration, if you have serialization errors, it means that you keep references on these objects.

Comment: That trick is good up to a point but sometimes you need to have detached model objects serializable and I mean "detached" in the ORM sense of detachment. For example a Modal form that edits a domain model object should be ORM detached while the form remains open and then during onSubmit it needs to be ORM reattached (via persist()) so that the changes can be saved back to the DB.